# Blocking the UI using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, userscripts, blockui

I'm writing a userscript. What I'm trying to do is really simple. I need to block the UI while the script does some background tasks. I saw this method in another SO question and I changed it a bit to suit me.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/Be4mK/). When you click on the button, it covers up the UI.

Now since this is gonna be used on a webpage, I need to inject the following HTML part to the webpage through the script.

```
<div id="blocker">
<div>Loading...<img src="http://www.socialups.com/static/images/fbinventory/ajax_loader.gif"></div>
</div>
```

I did it like this.

```
var blockUI = document.createElement("div");
blockUI.setAttribute("id", "blocker");
blockUI.innerHTML = '<div>Loading...<img src="http://www.socialups.com/static/images/fbinventory/ajax_loader.gif"></div>'
document.head.appendChild(blockUI);
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nK0de/zkzQy/) for a clear idea.

But it does not work. I tried several ways to tackle the problem but to no avail .Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Thank you.

**P.S** - I need to do this without using jQuery or the library blockUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to append your div to the body of the document. See: http://jsfiddle.net/zkzQy/1/

or like this in your code:

```
document.body.appendChild(blockUI);
```

Comment: oh man, how come I didn't try that out! stupid! Anyway, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to append stuff to `head`; append it to `body` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/dAKQX/

Answer (score 3):

Don't put the block `div` in the `head` section of your document. Use `document.body.appendChild(blockUI);` instead.